# Is there a hook after user confirmation?

Tags: users

I want to add a content type after a user registers to the site.

I tried `hook_user_save()` but it saves the content type before the user confirms his e-mail.

Is there a hook after e-mail confirmation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although this approach uses modules, I add nodes after users confirm their e-mails using [Logintoboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) and [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules).  The Logintoboggan rules integration adds a new event, `When the user account is validated`, which will allow you to perform actions upon e-mail confirmation.

Comment: Be sure to install the **LoginToboggan Rules Integration** module from the **LoginToboggan** project.

Answer (score 8):

This does the job for me:

```
/**
 * Implements @see hook_user_presave
 */
function hook_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  if ($account->uid // user is not new
      && $account->status === "0" && $edit['status']==1) { // user is being activated
  }
}
```

Comment: I had to use `if($account->uid && $account->original->status == 0 && $account->status == 1)`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working in Drupal 9 anymore. When the user clicks on the one-time link and saves his/her account after filling the password, the original status is already 1.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the LoginToboggan module for e-mail validation and you don't wish to use the rules module you can simply mimic the module's validation response (exploiting a temporary `logintoboggan_email_validated = TRUE` account property that's pushed to hook_user_update) yourself in code:

```
 /**
 * Implement hook_user_update()
 *
 */
function yourcustommodule_user_update(&$edit, $account) {
  if (!empty($account->logintoboggan_email_validated) && !isset($account->your_custom_action)) {
        $account->your_custom_action = TRUE;

        // Do what you want here

  }
}
```

Since core and other modules will also invoke hook_user_update you'd want to implement something to avoid repeated actions. In this example I set another property on the $account once the action is initiated but you can impose finer control if necessary.

Note that if using LoginToboggan for automatic e-mail validation IOco's method won't work (among the many reasons - during a hook_user_presave, the $account->status == 1 (it's just the role is in your elected "pre-authorised" state).