# How do I assign a role to a user after the user's email is confirmed?

Tags: hooks, emails, users, tokens

I want to assign a role to a user after the user confirms his/her email.

How do I do this?

Comment: Please mention your Drupal version (6 or 7 ?)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to take a look at [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) and [LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) (as per [this answer on Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30219/is-there-a-hook-after-user-confirmation)).

Rules will allow you to add a "trigger", such as adding a role to a user, and LoginToboggan will provide the "trigger" for when the account is validated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hook_user_login(&$edit, $account)` which is called from `user_login_finalize()`.

When $edit parameter is empty is because is called from `user_pass_reset()` menu callback:

```
// user_login_finalize() also updates the login timestamp of the
// user, which invalidates further use of the one-time login link.
user_login_finalize();
```

This example should work:

```
function MYMODULE_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  if (empty($edit)) {
    // @todo Add role to $account->roles array
  }
}
```