# Perform action when new user verifies email link

Tags: 7, emails

I am looking to catch the event when new user updates password after clicking on link in the email, right after one time login.

I actually want to perform an action right after user sets password after validating/clicking on one time login link in welcome email.

I have gone through this: [Is there a hook after user confirmation?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30219/is-there-a-hook-after-user-confirmation)

However, it does not solve my problem as explained below:

I used this condition to check if user is just created:

```
if ($account->uid // user is not new && $account->status === "0" && $edit['status']==1)
```

The issue with this is it holds usable for me in case if admin approves pending creation. In my case I don't want admin to approve, i want drupal to send email to user for confirmation. According to my workout, when admin approves, then above condition works, because status is changed from 0 to 1 so i can do some work at this change. But without admin, when user creates account, it is automatically activtaed, so I can't grab with this condition to perform my work at this event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a hook after user confirmation?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30219/is-there-a-hook-after-user-confirmation)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I worked with following to check if user is just created:
  if ($account->uid // user is not new
      && $account->status === "0" && $edit['status']==1)

This holds true if admin approves pending creation. In my case I don't want admin to approve, i want it to send email to user on for confirmation. According to my workout, when admin approves, then above condition works, because status is changed from 0 to 1 so i can do some work at this change. But without admin, when user creates account, it is automatically set to active, so I can't grab with this condition.

Comment: So I already checked that link: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30219/is-there-a-hook-after-user-confirmation

It didn't work that's why I asked this question.

Comment: I am afraid that as long as there is nothing in the *question* that tells us that you've already checked that link, it is still a duplicate.  You need to tell us what you tried, what the exact outcome was, and any errors you observed. Until you do, this looks like a duplicate to me. PS: Don't add detail in comments, they're for discussion, not for adding detail to a the question. Click the link "edit" to edit the question.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. I have explained in question above that what i tried and what were results those don't suite my need.

Answer (score 0):

I also updated the link your posted to.

If you're using the LoginToboggan module for e-mail validation and you don't wish to use the rules module you can simply mimic the module's validation response (exploiting a temporary `logintoboggan_email_validated = TRUE` account property that's pushed to hook_user_update) yourself in code:

```
 /**
 * Implement hook_user_update()
 *
 */
function yourcustommodule_user_update(&$edit, $account) {
  if (!empty($account->logintoboggan_email_validated) && !isset($account->your_custom_action)) {
        $account->your_custom_action = TRUE;

        // Do what you want here

  }
}
```

Since core and other modules will also invoke hook_user_update you'd want to implement something to avoid repeated actions. In this example I set another property on the $account once the action is initiated but you can impose finer control if necessary.