# Is there a hook invoked after user confirmation?

Tags: 8, users, hooks

[This question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30219/is-there-a-hook-after-user-confirmation) asks it (presumably for Drupal 7), but the solutions all appear to be specific to D7 and not applicable in D8, so that's effectively a different question.

It appears that [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/8.7.x) could be used used, but what checks would need to be done to check that it's the user confirmation (password added)?

Comment: You want to check the user added password first time or when the user changes their password?

Comment: When the user has added their password for the first time (from that first email).